# Jquery: Append array elements to div

Tags: html, jquery

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customers__photo', function(){
  
  let img_array = $(this).children().attr('src').ToArray();
  img_array.forEach(function (src) {
    $(".pushed").append('<img src="${'img_array.src'}" class="reviews__photo">');
   });
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="1">
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 1.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a1">
  </div>
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 2.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="customers__photo" data-id="2">
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 3.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a1"></div>
    <div class="customers__photo item">
      <img src="./ДИВАН 4.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pushed"></div>
```

How can I get children's only src attribute value and append image with these src values to div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customers__photo', function() {

  let img_array = $(this).children().map(function()  {return $(this).attr("src")}).get();
  img_array.forEach(function(src) {
    $(".pushed").append(`<img src="${src}" class="reviews__photo">`);
  });
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.customers__photo', function() {

  let img_array = $(this).children().map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("src")
  }).get();
  img_array.forEach(function(src) {
    $(".pushed").append(`<img src="${src}" class="reviews__photo">`);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="1">
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 1.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a1">
  </div>
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 2.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="customers__photo" data-id="2">
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 3.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a1"></div>
  <div class="customers__photo item">
    <img src="./ДИВАН 4.jpg" class="reviews__photo" data-id="a2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pushed"></div>
```

Comment: How did You do that?)))))

Comment: How can I know which function can I use after one?

Comment: Where can I read exctly about this example?

Comment: @AzizxonZufarov you can read more here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: What about : How can I know which function can I use after other? Is there any jquery object model tree?

Comment: @AzizxonZufarov Not really, you just learn by experiance

Comment: I have forgotten one div please can You rewrite code for me? Look to html